# Unable to use expression on excel connection manager in SSIS 2017

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to loop through excel files in a directory and perform a data flow task in SSIS.

The For-Each Loop container seems pretty simple to set up:

[image: For-Each Loop]

I map to a variable called FileNameTemp.

[image: For-Each Loop 2]

Inside the For-Each Loop, I have a data flow task where the source object is an Excel Source with an Excel Connection Manager.  I use the FileName temp to set the File Name of the ExcelFileName:

[image: Excel File Manager]

My problem is whenever I try to run the package, I get the error below:

> [Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
>   0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Access
>   Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Failure creating
>   file.".

I found other similar posts.  I definitely have permission to write to this folder.  If I remove the expression and just open the same file over and over it works.  I also set DelayValidation to true on pretty much every level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the "C:..." from your expression definition.  The For-Each file enumerator will give the full path.

In the future you can set a breakpoint on your data flow task and view the value of your variable that you set in the locals tab.

Comment: OMG I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer, just more verbose than @mike Baron's answer is that in the ForEach Loop Container, the radio button is checked for "Fully Qualified" with the result pushed into our variable `@[User::FileNameTemp]`

Each file found in the specified source folder C:\SourceCode\ExcelSourceFinancialReconcilliation is in turn going to be assigned to that variable in the form of

- C:\SourceCode\ExcelSourceFinancialReconcilliation\file1.txt
- C:\SourceCode\ExcelSourceFinancialReconcilliation\file2.csv
- C:\SourceCode\ExcelSourceFinancialReconcilliation\file2.xls

Then, when we set the Expression on the Excel Connection Managers `ExcelFilePath` property, we need to just use `@[User::FileNameTemp]`  As it stands, the expression is doubling up the path so that Excel is attempting to find

```
C:\SourceCode\ExcelSourceFinancialReconcilliation\file1.txt\C:\SourceCode\ExcelSourceFinancialReconcilliation\file1.txt
```

As a general rule, only use a direct variable in the Expressions associated to "objects" in SSIS. Property1 = @Variable  The reason for this, is that you cannot put a break point to on the evaluation to determine why @Property1 = "Foo" + @Variable is invalid. If you create a custom variable @Property1Variable = "Foo" + @Variable  and then assign @Property1 = @Property1Variable, you can put a breakpoint in the package and then inspect the value of the SSIS variable. It's much easier to find problems this way.

Possibly helpful other answers on the subject

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18640174/181965
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21536893/181965